# Windows Script to Copy Files from source to destination only if the destination file is smaller or doesn't exist

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, script

I have two directories with similar files

C:\dir1 and C:\dir2

I need to create a script that will copy the contents of Dir 1 to Dir 2 but only copy the file if the source file has a larger file size then the destination file or if the file doesn't exist.

I haven't been able to find a way to do this with powershell or cmd.

Comment: Does it has to be only 'larger' files ? Or do you want to copy 'changed' files ?

Comment: search for PowerShell Filesystemwatcher

Comment: Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\Dir1" | Where-Object {-Not $_.PsIscontainer} | % {
    $file1 = $_.FullName;
    $file2 = $file1 -replace ("C:\Dir", "C:\Dir2")
    If (Test-Path $file2)
    {
        $file1s=$_.Length
        $file2s=(Get-Item $file2).Length
        if ($file1s -gt $file2s)
        {
            Copy-Item $file1 "C:\Dir2" -Force
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Copy-Item $file1 "C:\Dir2"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this script really helped me out. The part i was missing is being able to use the .length part to extract a list. Just a note though. This line ("C:\Dir", "C:\Dir2") is incorrect because the regex expression recognize the \ as part of the expression I fixed it with guidance from this topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333675/replace-path-in-powershell-string. Thanks again

Comment: Actually, it isn't wrong because RegEx autoresolution is off in PowerShell. RegEx in PowerShell works only when you supply the string to a RegEx consuming cmdlet. Get-ChildItem does not consume RegEx. HINT: PowerShell autocomplete function gives you the same output.